# Is "to anagram" an established verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests, is-it-a-word

> To his amusement, Jason realized that the words Madam Curie *anagrammed* to Radium Came.

Is the above sentence idiomatic? I am not sure if I can use *anagrammed to*. If this is inacceptable, what is the best verb or verb phrase to express the desired meaning?

Comment: *Grammatically* it is correct. You don't really mean to ask if it is correct *grammatically*. Any past-tense verb in that position is grammatically correct. Any verb at all. Including non-existent ones.

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly. In the future, please make sure to not call things "grammar" that are not grammar.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "established".

Comment: Any noun can be verbed, but it weirds the language.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1443/) reference.

Comment: "In a perfect anagram, every letter must be used, with exactly the same number of occurrences as in the **anagrammed** word or phrase." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram

Comment: n., v. -grammed, -gram•ming. --  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anagram

Comment: anagrammed 1. simple past tense and past participle of anagram  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anagrammed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general form is '**A**  [*is an anagram of*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anagram) **B**'

> Anagram - **noun**
>
> 1 - a word, phrase, or sentence formed from another by rearranging its letters: “Angel” **is an anagram of** “glean.”.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Thus in your example:

> To his amusement, Jason realized that 'Madam Curie' was an anagram of 'Radium Came'

Comment: Can you explain why you use "is" rather than "was" here.

Comment: Because 'Madame Curie' *is* an anagram of 'Radium Came' throughout the continuum of time. Jason only *realised it* in the past. I am citing no codified rule, so I accept I may be wrong in that usage, but it is what I would say if I were to say it.

Comment: But the OP and all the other examples match the tense of the comparison to the tense of the word "realized".

Comment: Yeah, I know that the OP's sentence was incorrect. Personally I would have used _"anagrammed"_ with double m. Ehm, anyway. I can't cite a rule, your sentence just feels better with _was_ to me. Apparently, my gut feelings are a bit off.

Comment: Following discussions here (http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75271/mixture-of-past-and-present-tense) I defer to consensus that, although both are acceptable, the past tense is *more* acceptable and edit my answer accordingly. Fortunately it doesn't change the meat of my answer in relation to the OP :)

Comment: Please see my comments at OP

Answer (score 11):

*Anagram* is not a verb — although any word **can** be verbed, it weirds English.

The verb form is *anagrammatise* [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anagrammatize?q=anagrammatise)].

However, consider ***rearrange***:

> To his amusement, Jason realized that the words *Madam Curie* ***could be rearranged*** to *Radium came.*

Comment: -1 Oh that weirds everything. See my comments at OP.

Answer (score 9):

***anagram*** is indeed a verb, and ***anagrammatize*** its alternative  form. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anagramming%2Canagrammatising%2Canagrammatizing%2Canagrammatizes%2Canagrammatises%2Canagrammed%2Canagrammatized%2Canagrammatised&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Canagramming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canagrammatising%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canagrammatizing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canagrammatizes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canagrammed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canagrammatized%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canagrammatised%3B%2Cc0)

> anagram (anagrammed; anagrammimg)
>
> *transitive verb*
>
> 1:  anagrammatize
>
> 2:  to rearrange (the letters of a text) in order to discover a hidden message [M-W](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anagram)
>
> *To his amusement, Jason realized that the words "Madam Curie" **anagrammed
> into** "Radium Came"*
>
> *"L.A. Woman" anagrams into "AWOL Man"* [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yTGKYDEgFCAC&pg=PA149&dq=%22anagrams+into%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA6fqz3szJAhUGtBoKHRm8AfYQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=%22anagrams%20into%22&f=false)

Comment: This answer is correct. The verb (with and without -ize) is also found in Random House Kernerman as well as the OED Online. In the latter, the verb without -ize is given as being obsolete and rare, but that OED entry hasn't been updated in recent history.

Comment: This would be the right answer, (but then) in which case, the Q would be GR :) or at least found lacking in research.